# Прибли́женный и приближённый

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, значение-слов, части-речи

*Здание стало местом убийства Григория Распутина, человека, приближенного к семье императора Николая второго.*
Почему после слова «человека» в предложении ставится запятая?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написала так (имя собственное — Николай **II** или Николай **В**торой):
*Здание стало местом убийства Григория Распутина — человека, прибли́женного к семье императора Николая II.*

Следует различать разные по смыслу слова:
[прибли́женный](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x) (к кому-либо, к чему-либо) — причастие;
приближённый (матем., приблизительный) — прилагательное;
приближённый (кого) — прилагательное;
приближённый (состоящий в числе близких лиц) — в значении существительного.

Григорий Распутин не был приближённым Николая II, но был близок к семье императора, поэтому здесь по значению используется причастие *прибли́женный*.
Причастный оборот, стоящий после определяемого слова, отделяется запятой.

*События подаются через призму судьбы Николая Власика — очевидца и человека, приближенного к Сталину* (из статьи).

[Обособленные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108)